# Callback after update cell value programatically

Tags: ag-grid

I have a case where I need to update grid cell value via "editable" cell and via external action (programatically). On every update (regardless the source) I would like to call a callback (API call to sync data with backend).

For update through editable cell the callback I am using is `valueSetter`.

Programatically I am updating a cell value using `applyTransaction`. However `applyTransaction` doesn't call `valueSetter`.

I have extracted exactly the case to show the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-modules-tsp64f?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx

So my questions are:

1. What's the pattern to have a common callback for both cases?
2. Why `applyTransaction` is moving the row to the bottom of the table? (https://monosnap.com/file/dACiTbQ7wjj4aoBbZBwg5sRpgFOfQY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. The pattern I'd go for is to call your `valueSetter` on the column when you edit the cell via the button. You can do this by retrieving the column and executing the `valueSetter` on the column like this:

   ```
     const success = column.valueSetter({
       newValue: newValue,
       oldValue: oldValue,
       data: rowNode.data,
       node: rowNode,
       colDef: column,
       column: column,
       api: gridApi,
     });
   ```
2. Your `getRowId` function was always returning undefined. This function takes the parameter `params` from which you can then get your id like this:

   ```
     getRowId={(params) => {
       console.log(params.data.id);
       return params.data.id;
     }}
   ```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-modules-forked-lrrn2w?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A68%2C63&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0007356oxgnju5pg%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0003356ouordx6lo%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0004356owbt50s50%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0006356o7xoxm9w6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu9jl8cy0003356ouordx6lo%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0002356o48w355ki%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A68%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A63%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A68%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A63%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0003356ouordx6lo%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0002356o48w355ki%2522%257D%252C%2522clu9jl8cy0006356o7xoxm9w6%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0005356or1oeh81y%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0006356o7xoxm9w6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0005356or1oeh81y%2522%257D%252C%2522clu9jl8cy0004356owbt50s50%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu9jl8cy0004356owbt50s50%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).